# Why does my app crash when I use a Timer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I would like to use a view controller with a Timer inside a SwiftUI View, but it crashes.

```
class TimeViewController : UIViewController {

    var time = 0
    var timer : Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(startTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer()
    }

    @objc func startTimer() {
        time += 1
        print(time)
    }
     }


    struct TimeVC : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        typealias UIViewControllerType = TimeViewController

        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TimeVC>) -> TimeVC.UIViewControllerType {
            return TimeViewController()
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: TimeVC.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TimeVC>) {
        } }

    struct ContentView : View {
        var body: some View {
            TimeVC()
        } }
```

Comment: What does the crash message say?

Comment: What's crash message/location?

Comment: '-[__SwiftValue startTimer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000037bc480'

Comment: @MaricVikike, it looks like `self` in `timer` initialisation line is not `TimeViewController` you're thinking it is

Comment: Instantiate the timer in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Because the self means the class, not the instance. Default value of the variable is initialed in the class environment not the instance environment.